# How to fix an error with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium for web automation till yesterday it was all working fine but suddenly it started to give me this error-"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Selenium'", even when I have selenium installed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Has your version of Python changed? Can you import Selenium locally? Are you in a virtual runtime environment? If not, have you considered a virtual runtime environment?

Comment: Check the path to the driver,
check the version,
try to uninstall and reinstall the selenium

Comment: when I run where python in command prompt this comes is this ok-

Comment: C:\Users\user>where python
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\user>